# Angular feature routing module - Child component not loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a feature module that I load in the AppModule, the AppRoutingModule looks like

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: 'move-request/:id',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/move_requests/move_requests.module#MoveRequestModule'
  },
  ...
];
```

And the configuration of routing for the feature module looks like

```
const moveRequestRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: MoveRequestFormComponent,
    data: {title: 'Move Request'}
  },
  {
    path: 'move-request-success',
    component: RequestSuccessComponent,
    data: {title: 'Move request success'}
  },
];
```

I would like to navigate to `MoveRequestFormComponent` as the default component when `move-request/:id` is routed to, this works fine, but when I call

```
this.router.navigate(['/move-request-success', {}]);
```

In `MoveRequestFormComponent` after some response from the server, I get

```
zone.js:665 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'move-request-success' ; Zone: <root> ;
```

This configuration was working before I switched to Angular 6, Is it because of the change in the AppModule, where I have excluded this feature module as an import?

Any assistance on what I am missing would be much appreciated. As I have also tried with having a third component which will be the default component and uses the `router-outlet` to render the children and have a children property on this route to have as children

```
 {
   path: '',
   component: MoveRequestFormComponent,
   data: {title: 'Move Request'}
 },
 {
   path: 'move-request-success',
   component: RequestSuccessComponent,
   data: {title: 'Move request success'}
 },
```

But that also did not work, it stayed on the MoveRequestFormComponent, when `'move-request-success'` was navigated to.Or maybe I should change the approach?

Comment: Path in the children property could be `path: '/move-request-success'`

Comment: @DhiralKaniya I have tried that but no luck, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to import the feature module in AppModule as it is lazily-loaded. When you navigate to `move-request/:id/move-request-success`, the path matches the default route with `path:''`, and then it will look for and children of that route. You should add `pathMatch:'full'` to the first route, which is the default in this case. Since the mentioned route matches the first route and is unable to find and match any children, it is showing the error.

Comment: I think this answer is right but instead of move-request/move-request-success it should be move-request/:id/move-request-success

Comment: Yeah, missed that. Thanks @J. S. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

this.router.navigate(['/move-request-success', {}]);. If you add a / to a route this means you use absolute path from root. Have you tried without / ?

EDIT:

I think I see your problem. You navigate to a module with multiple components, which means after lazy loading the router configuration from the loaded module is used. This means

> move-request/:id

Is the root of your module and every subroute needs to include the modules root in the url:

Your route should be `move-request/:id/move-request-success`

Urls in lazy loaded modules are:

module root (in your case move-request/:id) + configured route of the specific component (in your case move-request-success)

Comment: yes just removed the '/' both in the navigate and in the config, no luck, thanks. With or without the pathMatch:'full'?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I have guessed that, I guess I have to change the architecture of the app, maybe take both components out of the module and use the root/app module instead